# need help with multiple column aggregate using pivot in mssql

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

below is the temporary table for class assessments. this table contain list of class assessment which include the assessment code, date of assessment, total item and passing percentage.

```
create table #class_assessments (class_assessment_id int identity(1,1),
                                 class_assessment_code  varchar(10),
                                 class_assessment_date  datetime,
                                 class_assessment_total_item decimal(8,3),
                                 class_assessment_passing_item  decimal(8,2))

insert into #class_assessments values ('a1', convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101), 10.0, 50.0)
insert into #class_assessments values ('a2', convert(varchar(10), getdate()+ 1, 101), 20.0, 50.0)
insert into #class_assessments values ('a3', convert(varchar(10), getdate()+ 2, 101), 30.0, 50.0)
insert into #class_assessments values ('a4', convert(varchar(10), getdate()+ 3, 101), 40.0, 50.0)
```

below is the employee assessments. this table contain list of employee who took the assessments

```
create table #emp_assessments (emp_assessment_id int identity(1,1),
                               class_assessment_id int,
                               emp_name varchar(100),
                               assessment_score decimal(8,2),
                               assessment_comment varchar(100))
insert into #emp_assessments values(1, 'emp_name1', 5.0, 'comment1-1')
insert into #emp_assessments values(1, 'emp_name2', 5.0, 'comment1-2')

insert into #emp_assessments values(2, 'emp_name1', 5.0, 'comment2-1')
insert into #emp_assessments values(2, 'emp_name2', 5.0, 'comment2-2')

insert into #emp_assessments values(3, 'emp_name1', 5.0, 'comment3-1')
insert into #emp_assessments values(3, 'emp_name2', 5.0, 'comment3-2')

insert into #emp_assessments values(4, 'emp_name3', 5.0, 'comment4-3')
insert into #emp_assessments values(4, 'emp_name4', 5.0, 'comment4-4')
```

my base table is #emp_assessment_scores. this table contains the summary or all employee assessments including the percentage score and status if passed of failed.

```
create table #emp_assessment_scores (id int identity(1,1),
                                     emp_assessment_id int,
                                     class_assessment_id int,
                                     emp_name varchar(100),
                                     assessment_score decimal(8,2),
                                     assessment_comment varchar(100),
                                     class_assessment_code varchar(10), 
                                     class_assessment_date  datetime, 
                                     class_assessment_total_item decimal(8,2),
                                     class_assessment_passing_item decimal(8,2),
                                     score_percent decimal(8,2),
                                     score_status varchar(10))
insert into #emp_assessment_scores
select  ea.emp_assessment_id,   
        ea.class_assessment_id, 
        ea.emp_name,    
        ea.assessment_score,    
        ea.assessment_comment,  
        ca.class_assessment_code,   
        ca.class_assessment_date,   
        ca.class_assessment_total_item, 
        ca.class_assessment_passing_item,
        ea.assessment_score / ca.class_assessment_total_item * 100,
        case when ea.assessment_score / ca.class_assessment_total_item * 100 >= ca.class_assessment_passing_item then 'passed' else 'failed' end
from #emp_assessments as ea inner join #class_assessments as ca on ea.class_assessment_id = ca.class_assessment_id
```

below is my pivot script

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @PivotColumnNames = N'';
SELECT @PivotColumnNames = @PivotColumnNames +  N', ' + QUOTENAME(class_assessment_code)
FROM( SELECT distinct(class_assessment_code) FROM #emp_assessment_scores AS p GROUP BY class_assessment_code ) AS x;

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
SELECT emp_name' + @PivotColumnNames + 'FROM (
SELECT  emp_name, score_percent, class_assessment_code FROM #emp_assessment_scores) AS j 
PIVOT (max(score_percent) FOR class_assessment_code in  ('+ STUFF(@PivotColumnNames, 1, 1, '') +')) AS s ';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

its shows the result

```
emp_name    a1      a2      a3      a4
emp_name1   50.00   25.00   16.67   NULL
emp_name2   50.00   25.00   16.67   NULL
emp_name3   NULL    NULL    NULL    12.50
emp_name4   NULL    NULL    NULL    12.50
```

but i wanted to have the result shown below.

```
emp_name    a1_item a1_passing  a1_score    a1_percent  a1_comment  ai_status   a2_item a2_passing  a2_score    a2_percent  a2_comment  a2_status   a3_item a3_passing  a3_score    a3_percent  a3_comment  a3_status   a4_item a4_passing  a4_score    a4_percent  a4_comment  a4_status
emp_name1   10.00   50.00       5.00        50.00       comment1-1  passed      20.00   50.00       5.00        25.00       comment2-1  failed      30.00   50.00       5.00        16.67       comment3-1  failed      null    null        null        null        null        null
emp_name2   10.00   50.00       5.00        50.00       comment1-2  passed      20.00   50.00       5.00        25.00       comment2-2  failed      30.00   50.00       5.00        16.67       comment3-2  failed      null    null        null        null        null        null
emp_name3   null    null        null        null        null        null        null    null        null        null        null        null        null    null        null        null        null        null        40.00   50.00       5.00        12.50       comment4-3  failed  
emp_name4   null    null        null        null        null        null        null    null        null        null        null        null        null    null        null        null        null        null        40.00   50.00       5.00        12.50       comment4-3  failed
```

i wanted to show per assessment the total item, passing percentage, score, score percentage and the status.

please help.